# nginx appears to be listing on port 80 but curl gets connection refused

Tags: curl, nginx

I have a machine set up with Ubuntu 16.04, nginx 1.10.2.  Here is the config I have set up for my dev site:

```
 server {
     listen   80; 
     listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
     server_name commandcenter.dev;
     root /var/www/commandcenter;
     index index.php index.html index.htm;
     location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         include fastcgi_params;
     }
 }
```

Everything starts up without error.  Nginx is running:

```
● nginx.service - LSB: Stop/start nginx


Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nginx; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-10-25 04:53:51 UTC; 8min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 11195 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/nginx stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11205 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nginx start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 1.3M
      CPU: 10ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─11216 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.con
           └─11218 nginx: worker process

Oct 25 04:53:51 commandcenter systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Stop/start nginx.
Oct 25 04:53:51 commandcenter systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Stop/start nginx...
Oct 25 04:53:51 commandcenter systemd[1]: Started LSB: Stop/start nginx.
```

And I think it's listing on port 80:

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep nginx
6:tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11216/nginx.conf
8:tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11216/nginx.conf
```

I can ping the server and reach it fine.  When I try to hit it up with curl or through the browser I get:

```
$ curl -I commandcenter.dev
curl: (7) Failed to connect to commandcenter.dev port 80: Connection refused
```

I'm not sure what I need to check out further or change to get through to nginx. I've checked both the error and access logs and there is nothing.

Comment: Is this on your local machine? If so, you need to configure `/etc/hosts/` and add `commandcenter.dev    127.0.0.1` to it so that it knows it must go via loopback interface.

Comment: This is not on my local machine, this is a virtual box.  The machine's IP is 10.10.10.1.  I've already put this in my hosts file.  I am able to ping the server, but any requests using curl/browser fail.

Comment: I see. Are you trying to access the site from within the virtual box or from the host?

Comment: I am accessing the site from the host.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to do some additional configuration. [This](http://aruljohn.com/info/virtualbox-access-guest-from-host-nat/) is one way to do it, but there are plenty of examples on the internet.

Comment: I've made the changes and it hasn't made a difference.  Are you sure that is necessary? I am able to reach the box from the host already, the only thing I am not able to reach is nginx, which I know is listening to port 80.

Comment: Have you configured the firewall on `10.10.10.1` to accept incoming connections on 80 port?

Answer (score 0):

Set `server_name` to

```
server {
    server_name .commandcenter.dev;
}
```

if you want to capture the domain, any subdomains and fully qualified domain names.

And server_name is optional if you have only one `server` block.

Comment: I've updated the server block to .commandcenter.dev, www.commandcenter.dev, as well as commenting out the server_name.  With all options, I no longer get the connection refused error, now I am just getting a connection timeout.

Comment: What URLs are you trying to access? Your location block is just set to match anything ending with .php. Create a simple html file, a simple location block for it and try to curl that.

Comment: I've tried www.commandcenter.dev, commandcenter.dev, typing the IP in directly, 10.10.10.1.  All give the same result.